# JAVA - > EXE Package not working in windows server 2008, why?

Tags: java, advanced-installer

I've created a Java program using Eclipse and I tried to pack Eclipse work space using Advanced Installer 11.6 trail, in order to create `.exe` file of my program.

So I generated those files (includes setup and cache files) and I copied them and pasted them into Windows Server 2008 R2 Desktop. Then I tried to run the `.exe` file and it's not working. It gave me the following error message:

> Failed to get the module path.

Providing that in my program I added a path for that contains the list of files that will be processed in that program.

The file was working on Windows 7 but not on Server.

Do I have to download Java or Eclipse again in Windows Server ?

Comment: Is their a difference between x86 / x64 on the server / desktop PC?

Comment: there has never been a "difference" between x86 and x64 - AMD64 is an extensions to x86.

Comment: @specializt wrong about IA64; it uses a completely different instruction set

Comment: wrong, IA32 _IS_ x86 : https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15213-s07/misc/asm64-handout.pdf hence IA64 is an extension to x86

Comment: Both of them were x64

Comment: @specializt, _Intel 64_ is what Intel now calls the 64-bit extensions to the x86 family.  _IA64_ is a completely different animal.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Intel_64

Comment: you have obviously not read the paper. At all.

Comment: @specializt: james is right; from the very paper you quoted: "Intel’s first foray into 64-bit computers were the Itanium processors, based on the IA64 instruction set.
Unlike Intel’s historic strategy of maintaining backward compatibility as it introduced each new generation of microprocessor, IA64 is based on a radically new approach" and "Since they had already used the name IA64 to refer to Itanium, they then faced a difficulty in finding their own name for this 64-bit extension. In the end, they decided to describe x86-64 as an enhancement to IA32, and so they refer to it as IA32-EM64T"

Comment: CPU compatibility is just one half of the story. Current 64-bit Linuces install without 32-bit libraries by default, and I believe it is possible to install Windows Server 2012 without the 32-bit subsystem. 32-bit executables won't run on such systems.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the file paths in the .ini file with the same name as the .exe. It is likely something stupid like C:\Program Files\ vs C:\Program Files (x86)\

```
[Application]
Application Type=gui
Failure Check=yes
Override WorkingDir=yes
Pair Product=C:\Program Files\....exe
[Class Path]
Class Path=C:\Program Files\....jar;C:\Program Files\...lib\*.jar;
[Java Runtime Environment]
Main Class=...
Maximum Version=any
Minimum Version=1.6
Preferred versions=1.8
Virtual Machine Parameters=-Xms32M -Duser.home="C:\Program Files\..." 
[Product Information]
Product Code={....}
Product Name=My Product
Upgrade Code={....}
```

Comment: all are correct ... but i dont know why it keeps saying : Failed to get the Path Module !!